# Google Assistant returns sometimes ACTION and sometimes TEXT

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

First time I'm asking a non-code question, so if It's incorrect/needs to change, please let me know...
I'm creating a list with products:

1. EY7546X slagschroefmachine | zonder accu's en lader
2. BDF343RHE Boor-/schroefmachine | 14,4v 1.3Ah Li-ion

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
          "carouselSelect": {
            "items": [
              {
                "description": "€192.00",
                "image": {
                  "accessibilityText": "productImage",
                  "url": "http://example.com/foo.jpg"
                },
                "title": "EY7546X slagschroefmachine | zonder accu's en lader",
                "optionInfo": {
                  "key": "596"
                }
              },
              {
                "description": "€195.30",
                "image": {
                  "accessibilityText": "productImage",
                  "url": "http://example.com/bar.jpg"
                },
                "title": "BDF343RHE Boor-/schroefmachine | 14,4v 1.3Ah Li-ion",
                "optionInfo": {
                  "key": "691"
                }
              },
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "de volgende producten:"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

When I'm executing the code, number 1 will invoke `actions.intent.TEXT`:

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "VOICE",
          "query": "EY7546X slagschroefmachine | zonder accu's en lader"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "EY7546X slagschroefmachine | zonder accu's en lader",
          "textValue": "EY7546X slagschroefmachine | zonder accu's en lader"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

And when clicking on number 2 it returns `action.intent.OPTION`:

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "VOICE",
          "query": "BDF343RHE Boor-/schroefmachine | 14,4v 1.3Ah Li-ion"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "OPTION",
          "textValue": "691"
        },
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "BDF343RHE Boor-/schroefmachine | 14,4v 1.3Ah Li-ion",
          "textValue": "BDF343RHE Boor-/schroefmachine | 14,4v 1.3Ah Li-ion"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Are there ways to always make it return OPTION? 
Or are there limits on the title I don't know about?

Comment: It **should** be an OPTION for both, if you're actually clicking on it. Is this happening on a particular device? On the simulator? Any additional information may help figure out what is going on.

Comment: It's happening on both mobile and simulator, I'm using dialogflow in combination with action on Google. Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm sending a lot of data in context-params with it. Maybe it has something to do with the vertical bars? Sorry for the late response...

Comment: I don't know exactly what for information would also make a difference...

Comment: I don't know exactly, either, but the more you *can* provide the better. Logs and screen shots from the simulator might help. As I said - it *should* be working the way you expect, so anything (detailed requests and responses, logs, code, etc) that could help someone else duplicate it or diagnose what is happening would help.

Comment: Ok, Ill ask first what I'm allowed to share. Then Ill share it.